# Create different generic objects based on argument type in C#

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

Suppose I have a list of many (say, 10) classes A1,..., A10 which all inherits from a base class `A` and I have a one-to-one mapping from them to 10 other classes B1,...,B10. I also have a generic class `MyClass<T>` And I wish to have a function `Func(A a)` which creates a `MyClass<B1>` instance if the input is an instance of `A1`, creates a `MyClass<B2>` instance if the input is an instance of `A2`, etc. I can do it using a switch statement but it gets messy if the number of classes grows. What is a good way of doing this?

Here is an concrete example: say the A classes are `Cat` and `Dog`, and the B classes are `Foo` and `Bar`, and I have another Generator class to generate these instances.

```
public class Generator{
    public Foo Generate(Cat c){ 
        // some code
    }
     
    public Bar Generate(Dog d){
        // some code
    }
}
```

and I have a generic class below

```
public class MyClass<T>{
   private T _t; 

   public MyClass(T t){
       this._t = t; 
   }
}
```

Now in the code I want to do something like this

```
Generator gen = new Generator(); 
dynamic animal = new Dog(); 
var result = gen.Generate(animal); // can be of type Foo or Bar  
var cl = new MyClass(result); // does not compile!
```

The last line does not compile because it is missing a generic type argument.

Please let me know if there's more details needed!

Comment: Can you share some code to get a better idea of what you need? i.e. one of the A classes, one of the B classes, and the mapping you are currently doing?

Comment: good idea -- just edited the question.

Comment: Can you share what the purpose of `MyClass` is? I know the issue right now is it can't be instantiated (not nicely, at least) because of the generic parameter. How and where is that generic field used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do note that when working with dynamics like this, it can be hard to break away from using dynamics upstream.
To specify the generic argument, one approach would be to create a factory method where the type can be inferred:

```cs
namespace ConsoleApp13
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main() {
            Generator gen = new Generator(); 
            dynamic animal = new Dog(); 
            var result = gen.Generate(animal); // can be of type Foo or Bar  
            var myClass = MyClass.Create(result);
        }
    }
    public static class MyClass
    {
        public static MyClass<T> Create<T>(T value) => new MyClass<T>(value);
    }
    public class Generator{
        public Foo Generate(Cat c){ 
            // some code
            return new Foo();
        }
     
        public Bar Generate(Dog d){
            // some code
            return new Bar();
        }
    }
    public class MyClass<T>{
        private T _t; 

        public MyClass(T t){
            this._t = t; 
        }
    }


    public class Dog
    {
    }

    public class Bar
    {
    }

    public class Cat
    {
    }

    public class Foo
    {
    }
}
```

But as other have said, in this case this is not necessary if you have class `A` creating `B` as dynamics and the `Generator` class will no longer needed:

```cs
namespace ConsoleApp13
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main() {
            var animal = new Dog();
            var myClassWithoutNewMethod = new MyClass<Bar>(animal.GetBar());
            var myClass = MyClass.Create(animal);
        }
    }
    public static class MyClass
    {
        public static MyClass<T> Create<T>(T value) => new MyClass<T>(value);
    }
    public class MyClass<T>{
        private T _t; 

        public MyClass(T t){
            this._t = t; 
        }
    }


    public class Dog
    {
        public Bar GetBar()
        {
            return new Bar();
        }
    }

    public class Bar
    {
    }

    public class Cat
    {
    }

    public class Foo
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can each type of A know how to produce it's corresponding B? Then you don't have to have a big decision tree testing the type of A in some separate code that then creates Bs...that code simply calls a.GetB().

Comment: Doing it this way would create the Bs, but I still don't get how I can create the generic classes? For example, say the Myclass<T> has a constructor which takes T as a parameter, then in order to construct an instance of MyClass B1, what should I put inside the angle bracket?